# Measure traffic to my website

Tags: web-traffic

I have a simple website. Now I need to measure traffic to my website. I need to go for some strategies to improve the traffic. Can anyone suggest me how to measure the traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to add a hit counter. It doesn't necessarily even need to be visible, but you can see how many people visit your page. Depending on what your site is written in, you could write your own, otherwise, just search for a "hit counter".

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics is rather brilliant.

http://www.google.com/analytics/